# Controller doesnt have the alter request from the middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I have a custom middleware that edits requests like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $profileLocal = ProfileLocal::where(
        'id', JWTHelper::tokenExtractProfileLocalID($request->token)
    )->with('status')->first();

    if (empty($profileLocal) || $profileLocal->status->email_verified == 0 || $profileLocal->status->blocked == 1) {
        return $this->respondError('You dont have access to this store', 336);
    }

    $request->profileLocal = $profileLocal;

    return $next($request);
}
```

However, when i try to access `$request->profileLocal` In my controller:

```
public function deviceSet(DeviceRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->profileLocal);
}
```

I get null returned even though in my DeviceRequest if i try to `dd(request()->profileLocal)` it works fine?
Does anyone know what i may be doing wrong here?
I have noticed that if i use `request()->profileLocal` in my controller it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to  add add a value to the request and be able to access it as a property you can add it to the underlying `request` property:

```php
$request->request->add([
    'profileLocal' => $profileLocal
]);

// or $request->request->add(compact('profileLocal'))
```

Then you'll be able to access the value in your controller with:

```
$request->profileLocal
```

This value will also be included when you call methods like `all()` or `input()`.

Comment: That works great, i didn't realise i could use $request->request

Comment: @DevDaniel Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I was told that if I use:

```
$request->attributes->add(['profileLocal' => $profileLocal]);
```

In my middleware and then access it using:

```
$request->attributes->get('profileLocal')
```

It works, I dont know if this is the correct way though.

Comment: Thanks you @benJ